# Wrong Picture asynchronously loaded in UITableView-cell when scrolling fast

Tags: ios, swift, image, asynchronous, reusability

I have a UITable-View with a List of Users and their Profile Pictures.
I am loading the pictures (http://api/pictures/{userid}) one by one for each player asynchronous:

```
func loadImageAsync(imageUrl: URL, completionHandler handler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ image: UIImage?) -> Void){

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { () -> Void in

    if let imgData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl), let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            handler(true, img)
        })
    } else {
        handler(false, nil)
    }
}
```

In the completion handler in the cellForRowAt-Index-Fuction, I am setting the pictures.

```
       loadImageAsync(imageUrl: imageUrl!, label: ip) { (success, image, backlabel) -> Void in
            if(success){
                cell.profilePictureView.image = image
            }
        }
```

However, when I scroll very fast, some pictures get loaded in the wrong cells.
To prevent reuse-issues, I am "resetting" the image view after every reuse:

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        profilePictureView.image  = UIImage(named: "defaultProfilePicture")
    }
```

But why are still some images loaded false when scrolling fastly?

hmmm, this is what I thought too.

__Update:
So, I extended the function with a Label Parameter (type Any), that is returned back as it was put in the function. I tried to compare the parameter (is used the indexpath) with the current indexpath. Actually, this should work - shouldn't it?!

```
            loadImageAsync(imageUrl: imageUrl!, label: ip) { (success, image, backlabel) -> Void in

            cell.loader.stopAnimating()

            if (backlabel as! IndexPath == indexPath) {

                //set image...
```

But however, it doesn't show any effect. Do you know why or have any other solutions to fix this?

Comment: No, add an indexPath parameter as I indicated in my answer. Your code will linear work. Why would backLabel be an IndexPath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that if you scroll fast, the download may take long enough that by the time it's complete, the cell in question has scrolled off the screen and been recycled for a different indexPath in your data model.

The trick is to ask the table view for the cell at that indexPath in the completion block and only install the image if you get a cell back:

```
   loadImageAsync(imageUrl: imageUrl!, label: ip, for indexPath: IndexPath) { (success, image, backlabel) -> Void in
        if(success){
            let targetCell = tableview.cell(for: indexPath)
            targetCell.profilePictureView.image = image
        }
    }
```

### EDIT:

Redefine your loadImageAsync function like this:

```
func loadImageAsync(imageUrl: URL,
  indexPath: IndexPath, 
  completionHandler handler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, 
    _ image: UIImage?,
    _ indexPath: IndexPath ) -> Void) { ... }
```

### EDIT #2

And by the way, you should really save your images to disk and load them from there rather than loading from the internet each time. I suggest using a hash of the image URL as a filename.

Modify loadImageAsync as follows:

1. Check to see if the file already exists on disk. If so, load it and return it.
2. If the file does not exist, do the async load, and then save it to disk using the hash of the URL as a filename, before returning the in-memory image.

Comment: hmm the problem is, that I have called the loadImageAsync-Function in the cellForRowAtIndexPath-Function. Does it make sense to call the same function again?

Comment: There's no need to call it twice. Modify your function to take the IndexPath of the requested cell as a parameter, as I've indicated, and that should do it.

Comment: Did you follow my suggestion of saving the images as files to disk? You should edit your question to add the working code at the bottom, so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Because your completionHandler can be called after the cell has been reused for the next user, and possibly another image request for the cell has been fired. The order of events (reuse/completion) is not predictable, and in fact a later async request could complete before an earlier one.